# autentication in Session cookie VS security

Tags: php, session, cookies

I got a question about security and session cookies.
The site I'm building at the moment I use the folowing:

When A user is logged in correct I give the session a cookie 'authenticate'.
Further in the script I'm using this cookie.
like:

```
if ($_SESSION['authenticate'] === 'fail'){do something}
else if ($_SESSION['authenticate'] === 'pass'){do something else}
```

but now the question...
due to security reasons mine gut feeling says: NOT SECURE!!!....
is there a more secure way to do this whitout session cookies?
Ore is this totaly secure way?

thnx in advanced.

Comment: According to me it's secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between PHP sessions and cookies.

Cookies are strings that are sent by the server to the browser, and that the browser must send back to the server on every subsequent request, until the cookie expires.
For example, if the server responds with a request with the header `Set-Cookie: foo=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT`, on every subsequent request until 9 June 2012 the browser must send the *request* header `Cookie: foo=abc123`.
On the PHP script, `$_COOKIE['foo']` will be `abc123`.

PHP sessions are based on cookies, but they don't store the values inside a cookie.
If you store `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'abc123'`, the server will NOT send `foo=abc123` to the client as cookie, but will rather create a session *stored on the server* and will send as cookie only the ID of the session.
So, when you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start), PHP generates a new session on the server, with an auto-generated id (if you're interested, you can read the id with [`session_id()`](http://php.net/session_id)). It will then send (automatically) a cookie to the client similar to `phpsessid=PHP_SESSION_ID_HERE`. All of this is done automatically by PHP, and you don't need to worry about that.

At the end of this story, yes, your code is safe. That is because you're not setting a cookie `authenticated=pass` (which will be insecure, as clients can easily overwrite cookies), but you're instead storing that value in the PHP session storage and the client sees only the session id.

PS: instead of just storing a boolean 'authenticated', you may want to store more useful information in the session, like the user id of the authenticated user in the database or anything else that can be meaningful.

PS2: PHP sessions have legacy support for browsers that do not have cookies enabled, but in 2015 that's meaningless (I wonder who still disables cookies! - if you do that, 90% of the websites will stop working). As a consequence, you should ensure that you have these two ini settings: (docs: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies )

```
session.use_cookies 1
session.use_only_cookies 1
```

Comment: It should be noted (although somewhat offtopic as it is assuming the rest of the application is insecure) that you should bind the `session_id()` to the clients IP. This will help prevent session hijacking and cookie stealing. **+1 from me, great explanation**.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Thank you :) Speaking of binding the session to the IP... Some people may argue it's not 100% reliable, as (at least in the past) there were situations in which the same user could be connecting with different IPs, even in different classes (e.g. corporate). Another good idea is to bind the session to the user agent of the browser, as that's certainly not going to change for the length of a session.

Comment: Oh yes, I agree. By that I mean checking the `session_id()` is valid against the IP, not getting a `session_id()` by passing in an IP. This way, if someone hijacks your cookies and gets your `PHPSESSID`, they'll have to be on the same network, or spoof their IP(?) - Making it harder to hijack, yes, but impossible? Unsure.

Comment: Yup I understood your point. It's as easy as storing the IP (and/or user agent) inside `$_SESSION` and validating it on every page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....
Also i'm looking in that binding thing...
maybe something for another question ore a google search :)
I'm still leave this question open maybe somebody had another idea :)
... there are multiple roads to rome.....

Comment: Actually, I believe @Qualcuno explained the difference between cookies and sessions and touched on the security aspect quite well to warrant an accepted answer - but that's up to you `:)`

Comment: For somebody else who is looking in to binding your session,... this is what i found and maybe help why and how to bind your session :  http://www.cs.ru.nl/~rverdult/Prevent_Session_Hijacking_by_Binding_the_Session_to_the_Cryptographic_Network_Credentials-NORDSEC_2013.pdf